# How to send ctrl+click+i to RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

Basically in the title. I would like to use the keyboard shortcut for inspect element *within* the webdriver. I have tried:

```
remDr <- driver$client
webEl <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath',"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]")
webEl$sendKeysToElement(sendKeys = list("\ue008\ue009","i"))
```

and also with
`webEl$sendKeysToElement(sendKeys = list("\ue008\ue009""i"))`

But nothing at all happens.

Thanks.

Comment: not so sure keychords work anymore, but you can launch with an argument to open the dev tools.  For Chromedriver it's something like this:  options.addArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");  where "options" is the ChromeDriverOptions object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - if anyone's looking, this definitely works to open chromedriver with the inspect element tool open, but I'd need to toggle it off and on. Do you know if there's anyway of opening it and closing it mid-drive?

Comment: webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("i,"\ue008\ue009""))

Comment: This doesn't work either sadly - same result

Comment: can you share the link?